# Custom Window Style not showing in design view

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am attempting to customize the window style in a WPF application in VS2019 (.NET Core 3.1). I'm following along with a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TDOxHx-AMqQ), currently adding the style directly to the `MainWindow.xaml`. None of my style shows up in the XAML design view (in the video it does), however, the style shows correctly at runtime.

All other styles show up fine. I dug around looking for perhaps a window style I had set somewhere else but I'm not finding anything. At first, I was having an error on the inner `<WindowChrome.../>` saying "object of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.XSurface.Wpf.Window' cannot be converted to type 'System.Windows.Window'" but that issue appears to have resolved itself. I'm not sure if that is related or a clue.

Any idea what is going on and how to fix it? Or perhaps a hack to force a design-time style to take so I can see what I'm doing?

Code:

```
 <Window x:Class="FirmwareUpdater.MainWindow"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FirmwareUpdater"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:FirmwareUpdater.ViewModels" 
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         WindowStyle="None"
         WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
         x:Name="AppWindow"
         Title="Firmware Updater"
         Height="600" Width="800">
    
     <Window.Resources>
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MainWindow}">
             <Setter Property="Template">
                 <Setter.Value>
                     <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                         <Border Background="Gray" Padding="{Binding OuterMarginSize, FallbackValue=10}">
                             <Grid Background="Red">
                             </Grid>
                         </Border>
                     </ControlTemplate>
                 </Setter.Value>
             </Setter>
         </Style>
     </Window.Resources>
    
     <WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
         <WindowChrome 
             CaptionHeight="{Binding TitleHeight}"
             ResizeBorderThickness="0"
             GlassFrameThickness="0"
             CornerRadius="0"/>
     </WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
        
    
     <Grid>
         <!-- Displays pages for navigation-->
         <Frame x:Name="mainFrame" 
                MaxHeight="600" MaxWidth="800" Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" />
     </Grid>
    
 </Window>
```

Comment: Your problem is not with this code you showed.
I copied it completely.
It works fine for me both during development and when launching for execution.

Comment: @EldHasp: Thank you for checking. Is there perhaps an intermediary step I'm missing in the project settings? I kind of suspect this is just a bug in VS.

Comment: The `Microsoft.VisualStudio.XSurface.Wpf.Window` thing seems to be an editor problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78080146/746341

Answer (score 2):

Recently, I was following this tutorial series and got this problem too, no matter which designer I use: NetFramework or NetCore.
For me, the only way to see changes during design-time is to define the ControlTemplate with a key in Window.Resources and set Window's Template as DynamicResource:

```
<Window ...
        Template="{DynamicResource WindowBase}">
<Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="WindowBase" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

I don't know how much this solution is reliable, but at least I don't have to run my app to see changes.

**EDIT**

You can also move the ControlTemplate from Window.Resources to some ResourceDictionary and set it as StaticResource for your Window's template.