# WPF assign a Page to a Dependency Property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties, .net-8.0

**TL;DR:** Binding a `{StaticResource SomePage}` to a `DependencyProperty` of type `Page` gives the error `Microsoft.VisualStudio.XSurface.Wpf.Page is not a valid value for property...`

**Long Version**

I am trying to create a custom button that needs to be aware of a `Page`. So I made a custom control with a `DependencyProperty` like so:

```
public class MyButton : Button
{
  static MyButton() {
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyButton)));
  }

  public Page AssociatedPage {
    get { return (Page)GetValue(AssociatedPageProperty); }
    set { SetValue(AssociatedPageProperty, value); }
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty AssociatedPageProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("AssociatedPage", typeof(Page), typeof(MyButton));
}
```

Then I try to use it inside some window (xaml):

```
<controls:MyButton AssociatedPage="{StaticResource HomePage}"
                   Content="Home" />
```

Where `HomePage` is defined in the same window:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <local:HomePage x:Key="HomePage" />
</Window.Resources>
```

And `HomePage.xaml` exists and compiles (nothing weird there).

The error I am getting is `Microsoft.VisualStudio.XSurface.Wpf.Page is not a valid value for property 'AssociatedPage'`. I realize that's not the same as `System.Windows.Controls.Page`... where is that coming from? How can I make my example work?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Maybe use a Page URI, as [WPF Navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/navigation-overview) does.

Comment: Strange problem. But I would also suggest to not store complete Page instances in memory. It's far more efficient to store the data model of a page or as suggested the URI. It's also bad class design in general. The button should not depend on such unrelated details. The common way is to make use of the Button.Command and Button.CommandParameter properties to execute navigation. The button itself must not control navigation what it appears to do in your case as it apparently knows how to display a Page. That's not clean. .

Comment: There is another object that knows how to navigate and that this navigation involves a Page. The button's responsibility is only to trigger the process. A button is a pure action trigger and not the executor. I know this doesn't explain the error. At least fixing your class design will avoid that error

Comment: Can you please check if have accidently installed an unwanted or surface related package? It looks like a linker issue.

Comment: Also c heck your using imports. When you hover over the Page type in your code editor it will also show the fully qualified type. This way you can also verify if the namespace is correct. In general this kind of error message indicates mismatching namespace between the two types (that are supposed to be the same type).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR** Ignore the editor message, make sure your resource dictionaries are built as `Page`s and not `Resource`s, and look elsewhere for the source of the problem.

The message `Microsoft.VisualStudio.XSurface.Wpf.Page is not a valid value for property...` that appears when hovering over the posted binding is an editor bug.

Changing the binding

from `AssociatedPage="{StaticResource HomePage}"`

to `AssociatedPage="{Binding Source={StaticResource HomePage}"`

made the wrongful editor message disappear.

Note that a couple of visual studio updates later, the bug manifests more rarely. When it does happen, it's always because of binding to some control or a subclass of.